# Behavior with ng-show and ng-hide in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

This is my code:
html:

```
<div ng-controller="ButtonController">
   <button class=" circle-white btn btn-collapse-custom" ng-click="collapse(1); toggleBtn()">
     <i ng-show="imgbtn" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
     <i ng-hide="imgbtn" class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

js:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = function($scope , $rootScope ){
  $scope.imgbtn = true;
  $scope.toggleBtn = function() {
      $scope.imgbtn = $scope.imgbtn === false ? true: false;
  };
};
```

this work's fine.

the problem is when another button is clicked ,the previous click stay active so the cross don't change.

[first button ,  when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFQwZ.png)

[Now another button is clicked , and previous is active yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IUBk.png)

Idk how to change the 'active' , any other solution ?

Comment: what u want to achieve?

Comment: Just a friendly tip here... `$scope.imgbtn = !$scope.imgbtn;` instead of the ternary thing you're doing there.

Comment: You can use ng-class to swap the fa class instead of having 2 separate dom elements. Also, 'the problem is when another button is clicked ,the cross don't change .' what does this mean? where is the other button in the code? is it in the same controller?

Comment: ajmajmajma , yes is the same controller , i add some images.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing what you want to achieve, but you should try this:

```
<div ng-controller="ButtonController">
    <button class=" circle-white btn btn-collapse-custom" ng-click="collapse(1); imbtn = !imbtn">
       <i ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-down': imbtn, 'fa fa-times': !imbtn}">
       </i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please kabaehr you can help me again , please.

Comment: Sure, what´s your problem?